# How to fix cannot find symbol method bitmap()?

Tags: java, android, qr-code

I'm trying to generate QR code in my app with `com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:javase:2.4.0'` library.

This is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Bitmap myBitmap = QRCode.from("www.facebook.com").bitmap();
        ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        myImage.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
    }

}
```

I get an error saying:

> Error:(23, 58) error: cannot find symbol method bitmap()

How can i fix this issue?

Comment: *how can i fix this issue?* by reading the documentation ... android is not java se

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`From Docs`](https://github.com/kenglxn/QRGen#android-only), `Bitmap()` is only available in the android version so you have to use below dependency

```
 compile 'com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:android:2.4.0'
```

instead of java oriented dependency

```
com.github.kenglxn.QRGen:javase:2.4.0'
```

Comment: It fixed the issue but now it shows cant resolve method QRCode :(

Comment: Sorry I was importing the javase not android. Thannks